# Connect to webLogic from ant task?

Tags: ant, weblogic12c

Hi i am trying to connect to weblogic Server from build script here is my script

```
<target name="all" >
    <taskdef name="wldeploy" classpathref="wlappc.classpath" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy"/>
    <echo message="Here it is running fast swap"/>
        <fast-swap user="weblogic"
            password="Prima123Vera"
            adminurl="t3://localhost:7001"
            server="AdminServer"
            application = "primavera"
            />
    <taskdef name="wlserver" classpathref="wlappc.classpath" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLServer">
            </taskdef>
    </target>
```

But i am facing

```
**java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: t3**
            at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:357)
            at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
            at com.bea.wls.redef.ant.FastSwapTask.getJMXConnector(FastSwapTask.java:144)
            at com.bea.wls.redef.ant.FastSwapTask.execute(FastSwapTask.java:160)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Comment: Instead of `adminurl`, use `adminserverurl` and see that solves the issue. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/ant_tasks.html)

Comment: <fast-swap> does not support adminserverUrl